Rank numbers including NA()s in Excel 365
Let's say I have a list of numbers including a few NA()s.
In the previous versions of Excel I have used the following formula and it worked (not very elegant mind you):
=IFERROR(MATCH(F8, AGGREGATE(15, 6, F$2:F$10, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(F$2:F$10)))), 0), "")

I have updated it slightly in Excel 365 to:
=IFERROR(MATCH(F2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, F$2:F$10, SEQUENCE(COUNT(F$2:F$10))), 0), "")

And next completely re-wrote it as a LET formula (LET makes everything better ®):
=LET(
    values, F$2:F$10,
    ranks, SORT(FILTER(values, ISNUMBER(values)), 1, 1),
    IFERROR(MATCH(F2, ranks, 0), "")
)

The last version can be compacted to:
=IFERROR(MATCH(F2, SORT(FILTER(F$2:F$10, ISNUMBER(F$2:F$10))), 0), "")

All formulas work as they should, but I can't stop thinking I'm missing something to make the formula even more compact and shorter.  Any ideas?


Came to the same answer as Harun24hr, dynamic array version,  and can't let go of LET :) =LET(v, A$2:A$10, IFNA(XMATCH(v, SORT(v)), ""))

I think XMATCH() with SORT() may be simplest one. Try-
=IFERROR(XMATCH(F2,SORT($F$2:$F$10)),"")


